# How to show all processes in Erlang?

Tags: process, erlang

I need get all registered process. I input `register().` a

```
 mnesia_event,kernel_safe_sup,mnesia_monitor,mnesia_snmp_sup,
 mnesia_recover,mnesia_late_loader,mnesia_kernel_sup,inet_db,
 rex,kernel_sup,global_name_server,mnesia_checkpoint_sup,
 file_server_2,user,error_logger,global_group,mnesia_locker,
 standard_error_sup,popd_listener_sup,pop_fsm_sup,dets_sup,
 smtpd_listener_sup,disk_log_sup,disk_log_server,dets|...]
```

How can i get all names registered process, without `| ...]` (truncation)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

registered() is returning all the processes, but the shell is truncating output.

you can print the result to see everything:

```
io:format("~p~n", [registered()]).
```

Answer (score 56):

You can use [`registered/0`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/processes#registered-processes) like this,

```erlang
> rp(registered()).
```

[Documentation for shell here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/shell.html)

Comment: +1 for the best solution to this, I missed rp() for a short way to display all of a structure without typing io:format abominations all the time.  Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 12):

As long as your are in shell you can use [`regs()`](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/erlang-programming/9780596803940/ch04s04.html):

```
1> regs().

** Registered procs on node nonode@nohost **
Name                  Pid          Initial Call                      Reds Msgs
application_controlle <0.33.0>     erlang:apply/2                   65717    0
code_server           <0.38.0>     erlang:apply/2                  592348    0
disk_log_server       <0.129.0>    disk_log_server:init/1             323    0
disk_log_sup          <0.128.0>    supervisor:disk_log_sup/1          367    0
dtls_connection_sup   <0.70.0>     supervisor:dtls_connectio           84    0
dtls_udp_sup          <0.71.0>     supervisor:dtls_udp_sup/1           81    0
erl_prim_loader       <0.6.0>      erlang:apply/2                24923843    0
erl_signal_server     <0.46.0>     gen_event:init_it/6                 51    0
...

** Registered ports on node nonode@nohost **
Name                  Id              Command
ok
```

Comment: Any way to know which process causing cpu load..?

Comment: @knocker not really sure about that!

Answer (score 4):

I believe the easiest way is:

```
> io:write(registered()).
```

Comment: I raise you with `rp(registered()).` [Doc](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/shell.html)

Comment: @D.Nibbon: Why not write your own answer so we can upvote it properly?