# Full binary output

Tags: binary, erlang

I'm receiving data from tcp socket in binary view. In erlang shell i see:

```
<<18,0,0,0,53,9,116,101,115,116,32,103,97,109,101,1,0,0,1,
  134,160,0,3,13,64,0,0,0,20,...>>
```

How can i show all data without `...`

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the format part of [io:fwrite](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#fwrite-1). I assume that your data is output with format `P` or `W`:

> P
>
> Writes data in the same way as ~p, but takes an extra argument which is
>   the maximum depth to which terms are
>   printed. Anything below this depth is
>   replaced with ....

Try specifying a different format, for example:

```
io:fwrite("~p~n", [Data]).
```

Answer (score 13):

`> rp(Term).` [Documentation here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/shell.html)

This might not be what you want depending if you want to input rp(Term) in shell or want compiled code to output Term in shell.

[Another thread with some more alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415221/erlang-show-all-registered-process/5417050#5417050)